# python-dbg can't find Py_InitModule4 when debugging

Tags: python, gdb, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to debug a segfault i get in a multithreaded, qt webkit application. I installed python-dbg for the purpose of giving me pretty printing in gdb and get the following error on start

```
python2.7-dbg node.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node.py", line 4, in <module>
    import msgpack
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/msgpack/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from msgpack._msgpack import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/msgpack/_msgpack.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node.py", line 4, in <module>
    import msgpack
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/msgpack/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from msgpack._msgpack import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/msgpack/_msgpack.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

I get the same thing when I run a version of the script that doesn't use msgpack...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from planeswalker import PlaneswalkerParser
  File "/var/www/rails_projects/MCPro.com/lib/planeswalker/planeswalker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 20, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from planeswalker import PlaneswalkerParser
  File "/var/www/rails_projects/MCPro.com/lib/planeswalker/planeswalker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

in both cases its looking Py_InitModule4... any ideas python experts? Code runs fine (except for the segfault much later) with normal python 2.7

If there's an easier way to get pretty printing in gdb I'm open to that as well. Basically just looking for a python style stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

after a bit of poking it looked like there were bugs related to this in past ubuntu python-dbg libraries. I filed a bug in suit and found out I just didn't read documentation. It is required to install the -dbg version of a library (MySQLdb and PyQT4 in this case)

There is no version for message pack so i'm posting another question on how to do that

here was the bug report marked invalid for reference https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1040914