# create debug version of python package python-msgpack for Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, msgpack, messagepack

I need a version of messagepack that i can use with python2.7-dbg. How would I go about creating one?

for reference I've asked via an issue on github https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python and here's a little context [python-dbg can't find Py_InitModule4 when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098694/python-dbg-cant-find-py-initmodule4-when-debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PyDbgBuilds

http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/SpecialBuilds.txt

these references were really helpful. Also there's always the option of talking to the devs online via launchpad and mailing lists

thanks for the help